# AngularJS filters - undefined object

Tags: angularjs

I got this expression in my `index.html`:

```
{{place.file.name()}}
```

it contains a String like `tfss-24af16c3-df1f-4c35-a1e1-281bd3af7c7a-Flightreservation.pdf`.

I want to cut the first 42 characters by a filter:

```
{{place.file.name() | sliceFileName}}
```

The filter is this:

```
.filter('sliceFileName', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.slice(42);
  }
})
```

And it works. However, the console prints:

`[Error] Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'input.slice')`

I read somewhere that `input` is either `true`or `false` (don't know if it is correct). But it works as if `input` is the string.

Why does it still output an error?

Answer (score 1):

Error means that sometimes your input is not a string. It could be, for example, before your `place` object has been initialized.

For your purpose you just can use built-in [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter, because there already is some checks. It has second argument where you can set offset:

```
$scope.Infinity = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY // you need to provide that into scope, because you need to set upper bound of limit

{{ string | limitTo:Infinity:42 }}
```

See plunker with full demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/o1fIh84OhptZrsYZ0vIV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Because the filter get's evaluated before the content is loaded. You can check if the input has any content:

```
.filter('sliceFileName', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if(input) return input.slice(42);
  }
})
```

And you won't get the `console error` anymore.